# Is there anyway of converting uppercase to lowercase as well as modifying spaces to text in a file using SED

Tags: bash, text, replace, sed, substitution

I have some html text that I need to fix the URL text on. I need to:

1) convert text within the URL to lowercase
also
2) converting any spaces to hyphens within the URL
also
3) deleting any parenthesis from URL

I have multiple occurances of this pattern within each file:

`<div class="classname"><a href="/URL"><img src="${asset.image/url}" alt="TEXT" class="another-class-name" ></a></div>`

**Example:**
I want to change this pattern: `<div class="classname"><a href="/URL-EXAMPLE-ONE"><img src="${asset.image/url}" alt="TEXT" class="another-class-name" ></a></div>`

To: `<div class="classname"><a href="/url-example-one)"><img src="${asset.image/url}" alt="TEXT" class="another-class-name" ></a></div>`

I have a number of files, and want to do an infile substitution. The `/URL-EXAMPLE-ONE` could have any combination of SPACE, Parenthesis too.

I now have, using the suggestion below:

```
/sw/bin/sed -e '/<div class="mk-man-logo-mod5-m"><a href="\/[A-Z -{}&]*"></ {
   h;
   s/.*<div class="mk-man-logo-mod5-m"><a href="\/\(.*\)"><img.*/\1/;
   s/\(.*\)/\L\1/;
   s/[ &]/-/g;
   s/[()]//g;
   s/<img.*//;
   x;
   s/\(.*<div class="mk-man-logo-mod5-m"><a href="\/\)\(.*\)\(<img.*\)/\1\3/;
   G;
   s/\n//;
   }' $e
```

But the output I'm getting is, as an example:

**Original text:**
`<div class="classname"><a href="/ABC (D&E)"><img src="${asset.images/common/manufacturer_logos/medium/abb-m.gif}" alt="TEXT" class="another-classname" ></a></div>`

**Transformed text:**
`<div class="classname"><a href="/<img src="${asset.images/url}" alt="TEXT" class="another-classname" abc-d-ediv>`

**Actually want:**
`<div class="classname"><a href="/abc-d-e"><img src="${asset.images/url}" alt="TEXT" class="another-classname"></a></div>`

Could anyone help further?

Many thanks in advance,
Alex

Comment: Add the following to your sed command: `-e 's/ /-/g' -e 's/[()]//g'`. The first changes spaces to hyphens; the second deletes parentheses.

Comment: @savanto: That will make it `div-class="classname"` instead of `div class="classname"` in the output.

Comment: There's the `y///` command: `y/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPRSTUVWXYZ/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/` but it is probably too enthusiastic for your purposes.  You might have to play funny games with the hold space and the pattern space to make it work.  You can check/experiment whether your `sed` recognizes `\L` or `\U` (and `\E`) as escapes in the replacement part of `s///` to mean lower-case, upper-case (and 'end') mapping, but probably it won't.

Comment: @anubhava Good point. You can do `-e 's/ /-/3g'` to replace only the third space onward.

Comment: @savanto Would you be able to help further, please see my edited question above.

Comment: Please take a look at updated answer, let me know if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `sed` script to perform all of the substitutions:

```
sed '/<div class="classname"><a href="\/.*">/ { h; s/<div class="classname"><a href="\///; s/\(.*\)/\L\1/; s/ /-/g; s/[()]//g; x; s/\(<div class="classname"><a href="\/\)\(.*\)/\1/; G; s/\n//}'
```

### Explanation:

- `/<div class="classname"><a href="\/.*">/` perform commands only if pattern matched.
- `h` store copy of line in hold space.
- `s/<div class="classname"><a href="\///` remove all but the url.
- `s/\(.*\)/\L\1/` convert url to lower case.
- `s/ /-/g` convert spaces to hyphens.
- `s[()]//g` remove parentheses.
- `x` swap hold space with pattern space (now operating on original line again)
- `s/\(<div class="classname"><a href="\/\)\(.*)/\1/` remove url.
- `G` append hold space to pattern space
- `s/\n//` remove newline introduced by `G` command.

### Alternatively

If your data are always exactly as given in the example (ie. `<div class="classname"><a href="/URL">`) and you don't need a universal solution, you could use the following simpler script:

```
sed '/<div class="classname"><a href="\/.*">/ { s/\(.*\)/\L\1/; s/ /-/3g; s/[()]//g }'
```

This will match the pattern, convert everything to lowercase, delete all parentheses, and replace spaces with hyphens from the third space to the end of the line.

### Update

In response to the updated question, here is a new `sed` command that takes into account the additional `<img>` tag on the end.

```
sed '/<div class="classname"><a href="\/[A-Z -(){}&]*"><img.*<\/div>/ { # match pattern
  h; # hold copy of original string
  # replace original string with just url, converted to lowercase.
  s/\(<div class="classname"><a href="\/\)\([A-Z -(){}&]*\)\("><img.*<\/div>\)/\L\2/;
  s/[ &]/-/g; # convert spaces, ampersands to hypens.
  s/[(){}]//g; # remove parentheses, braces.
  G; # append original string after url. Looks like: "converted-url\n<div class="classname"..."
  s/\n//; # remove newline introduced by append G.
  # swap out URL in original string with converted url.
  s/\([a-z-]*\)\(<div class="classname"><a href="\/\)\([A-Z -(){}&]*\)\("><img.*<\/div>\)/\2\1\4/;
}'
```

Comment: many thanks for your response, this really does fill the missing blanks in my knowlege. I'll follow up your answer. Regards Alex

Answer (score 1):

Love it or hate it, sometimes Perl is the easiest.

```
perl -pe 's/<div class="classname"><a href="([^"]*)"/$1 =~ tr:A-Z ():a-z-:rd/e'
```

The regular expression could be adjusted if it is too general; I didn't do it because the regex in the OP seems to exclude hrefs with parentheses, but the request asks for parentheses to be deleted.